# MS Visual studio 2012 debugger is not working for solution those build on TFS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to debug an application remotely with MS Visual Studio 2012 debugger and that application is build on sever with TFS 2010. During debugging, I do not hit the break point and if I try to debug the same application with MS Visual 2010 remote debugger then ever things works as it should. If I build same application with MS Visual Studio 2012 and debug that that application remotely then debugger works fine. I could not find any reasonable answer on internet. One more thing to tell that .pdb files are available along .dlls and .exe.

Comment: You will have to go more in details what exactly your doing, to debug you need debuging symbols to be present and loaded (.pdb files) where the assembly is being loaded from.

Comment: You need to keep the .pdb files from your TFS server: http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know

Comment: Yes, I am keeping the .pdb files from server build. I am copy the whole folder from the server. I have been working with VS 2010 and I never saw this problem. It happens with VS 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS VS development team's answer related to this problem is available here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789529/ms-visual-studio-2012-remote-debugger-in-not-working-for-application-build-on-tfs-2010